# I uninstalled and reinstalled the VS Code Flutter extension, and now every time I open VS Code, the Flutter Daemon fails to start

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

After uninstalling and reinstalling the Flutter VS Code Extension I can no longer access any virtual machines. Every time I open VS Code the Flutter Daemon Fails to start, and it only says "no devices" this is the log when Flutter Daemon fails to start. Is there any way I can stop this from happening and be able to use virtual devices again?

```
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\.windows-build-tools\python27\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\.windows-build-tools\python27\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\atom\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\flutter
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\flutter for flutter.bat
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Python27\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Python27\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Python27\Scripts
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Python27\Scripts\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\.windows-build-tools\python27\
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\.windows-build-tools\python27\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\atom\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Anchey Peng\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk for dart.exe
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 31 for experiement 'lsp-default'. Experiment is enabled for <= 100
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Experiment 'lsp-default' is activating (not first time)
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.26.0
Flutter extension: 3.26.0 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.60.2
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.14.2
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\flutter
    Ver: 2.5.1

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[12:10:45 AM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["--no-sound-null-safety","daemon"]
[12:10:45 AM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\flutter
[12:10:45 AM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[12:10:45 AM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 6228
[12:10:45 AM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ==> [{"id":"1","method":"emulator.getEmulators"}]
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat with args ["global","list"]
[12:10:45 AM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 27508) Logging data for process...
[12:10:45 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["C:\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\snapshots\\analysis_server.dart.snapshot","--lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.26.0"]
[12:10:45 AM] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 30320
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Extension:Startup timing: 365ms
[12:10:45 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 5018
[12:10:45 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":6228,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.60.2"},"locale":"en-us","rootPath":"c:\\Users\\Anchey Peng\\Desktop\\Coding\\Hackathons\\BigRedHacks2021\\bigredhacks2021","rootUri":"file:///c%3A/Users/Anchey%20Peng/Desktop/Coding/Hackathons/BigRedHacks2021/bigredhacks2021","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failu…
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get":
[12:10:45 AM] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.26.0
Flutter extension: 3.26.0 (activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.60.2
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.14.2
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\flutter
    Ver: 2.5.1

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[12:10:46 AM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 27508) devtools 2.6.0
[12:10:46 AM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 27508) exited (0, null)
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] <== Content-Length: 398
Content-Type: application/vscode-jsonrpc; charset=utf-8

{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"capabilities":{"executeCommandProvider":{"commands":["edit.sortMembers","edit.organizeImports","edit.fixAll","edit.sendWorkspaceEdit","refactor.perform"],"workDoneProgress":true},"workspaceSymbolProvider":true,"workspace":{"workspaceFolders":{"supported":true,"changeNotifications":true}}},"serverInfo":{"name":"Dart SDK LSP Analysis Server","version":"2.14.2"}}}
[12:10:46 AM] [General] [Info] Analyzer:Startup timing: 1100ms
[12:10:46 AM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 27508) closed (0, null)
[12:10:46 AM] [General] [Info] devtools version 2.6.0 appears to be latest so returning Valid
[12:10:46 AM] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat with args ["global","run","devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[12:10:46 AM] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[12:10:46 AM] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 6228
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 52
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"initialized","params":{}}
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] <== Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: application/vscode-jsonrpc; charset=utf-8

{"id":1,"method":"workspace/configuration","params":{"items":[{"scopeUri":"file:///c:/Users/Anchey%20Peng/Desktop/Coding/Hackathons/BigRedHacks2021/bigredhacks2021","section":"dart"},{"section":"dart"}]},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 6165
[12:10:46 AM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[{"additionalAnalyzerFileExtensions":[],"allowTestsOutsideTestFolder":false,"automaticCommentSlashes":"tripleSlash","cliConsole":"debugConsole","enableSdkFormatter":true,"enableServerSnippets":false,"enableSnippets":true,"env":{},"closingLabels":true,"analysisServerFolding":true,"analysisExcludedFolders":[],"flutterCustomEmulators":[],"debugSdkLibraries":false,"debugExternalPackageLibraries":false,"showDartDeveloperLogs":true,"showSkippedTests":true,"flutterS…
[12:10:50 AM] [DevTools] [Info] <== {"event":"server.started","method":"server.started","params":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":9100,"pid":33324,"protocolVersion":"1.1.0"}}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix that error? I have the same issue wuth WSL Vscode